# Upgrading Spring Boot from 1.3.2 from 1.4.0 causes "No aliases found in result tuple!"

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I decided to upgrade my Spring Boot App from 1.3.2 to 1.4.0. Unfortunately this breaks almost all of my JPA Repository queries that I specified with `@Query` annotation.

For example

```
public interface MatchRepository extends JpaRepository<Match, MatchKey> {
    // ...
    @Query("SELECT min(m.hourOfTheMatch) FROM Match m WHERE m.primaryKey.matchday = :matchday")
    DateTime getFirstMatchStartDateTime(Matchday matchday);
    // ...
}
```

The `MatchKey` is an `@EmbeddableId` in this case, but I don't think it is the root case.

The query ends with a runtime exception.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No aliases found in result tuple! Make sure your query defines aliases!

I have no idea what this is and what has been changed between those versions.

What I have found is [this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-885) JIRA issue but I do not use directly the version of `spring-data-jpa` in my `pom.xml`. I use only `spring-boot-starter-parent` in version `1.4.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `DateTime` from Joda. Switching to JDK 8 date and time types (`ZonedDateTime`) and upgrading to Hibernate 5.2.2.Final solved the problem.

In fact [Oliver Gierke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18122/oliver-gierke) helped a lot in [this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-885) discussion.